# How do I correctly remove a child xml tag with xml.etree.elementtree?

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, elementtree

I'm trying to remove all child tags from a xml file while keeping the parent tags intact. I have tried looping through the elements to make a list and remove them that way, but the elementtree module does not like that.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET    

tree = ET.parse("myfile")
root = tree.getroot()

for parent in root.find('parent'):
    child = parent.findall('child')
    #print(len(child))
    root.remove(child)

tree.write("myfile")
```

I left the print function hashed out to show that I can see the correct length of the list there.

The remove call returns an error

```
TypeError: remove() argument must be xml.etree.ElementTree.Element, not list
```

Where am I going wrong? Am I oversimplifying how ElementTree removals should work?

Answer (score 2):

`findall` return an array, thus your `child` is also an array. If you want to remove all the children, you have to make another loop for `child` as

```
for parent in root.findall('parent'):
    for child in parent.findall('child'):
        parent.remove(child)
```

According to the [19.7.1.3. of the xml package docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html)

> Element.findall() finds only elements with a tag which are direct
> children of the current element. Element.find() finds the first child
> with a particular tag

Thus if you only have a single child, you can use `find` instead of `findall`.
thus the following snipped would then be valid

```
for parent in root.find('parent'):
    child = parent.find('child')
    parent.remove(child)
```

**Update with a fully working example with write to file what turns**

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET    

tree = ET.parse("test.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

for parent in root.findall('parent'):
    for child in parent.findall('child'):
        parent.remove(child)
tree.write("test1.xml")
```

This snippet would turn

```
<foo>
    <parent>
        <child>
            <grandchild>
            </grandchild>
        </child>
        <child>
            <grandchild>
            </grandchild>
        </child>
        <child>
            <grandchild>
            </grandchild>
        </child>
    </parent>
    ...
</foo>
```

into

```
<foo>
    <parent>
        </parent>
    ...
</foo>
```

Comment: Thanks. The loop appears to work as it will run error free and the xml file indicates that it needs to be reloaded as a change has been made. However no change actually occurs upon reload. Do you know how python handles the file change? Are we storing the change in memory and losing it along the way before rewriting?

Comment: I added a fully working code example that does what you need as well as updated the code examples in the answer.

Comment: And to answer your question, xml module loads the entire file into the tree variable (or throws the exception if the xml is not valid). The `remove()` method in your file probably failed to find the right element to delete thus the final output in the file not changing. The `write` method still updated the file, even if with the identical content, so you were still notified of it changing despite not getting the desired result

Comment: If I use findall() on the parent and child, I get `ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list`. 
I added something like this `while True:
            try:
               root.remove(child)
            except:
                break` to the loop which removed that error but the file still does not get updated. I didn't think I had to explicitly set the location of the parent eg `for parent in root.find('./root/grandparent/parent')`. Is this the case?